# Alternatives in pure function construction

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, core-language, expression-construction

When I declare a function `f` in the following form:

```
f[a|b] := 1
```

then I can use it like:

```
f[a] (* gives 1 *)
```

But when I try to use the form:

```
f=Function[a|b,1]
```

I get the following error, and I can't use it:

`Function::flpar: Parameter specification a|b in Function[a|b,1] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.`

Why does `Alternatives[a,b]` not "work" like a list `{a,b}` in this case?

Comment: `Function` does not allow you to use patterns in the variable specification. You can't do things like `Function[n_?NumericQ, ...]` either. All you can do, is list the names of the variables that the function takes.

Comment: Do you know if there is a logical reason or it is a technical limitation?

Comment: `:=` creates a definition based on pattern matching. so, on the lhs `f[a|b] := ` the pattern in the argument of `f` is the literal expression `a|b`. It's actually a totally different mechanism of substituting in values than the `Function` head! the `Function` head is for anonymous functions, and the first argument is just a list of the formal parameters used in the functions body, which are filled from the argument(s) sequentially—it's not a pattern that is matched against the argument.

Comment: To get an equivalent definition of `f` to the `:=` definition, consider `f=Replace[{(a|b) :> 1}]`

Comment: You can also use `f[a | b] = 1;` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Function` does not do pattern matching. If you need pattern matching, you can do it manually:

```
Function[x,
  Switch[x,
    a|b, 1,
    _, 0 (* this is the default choice for input that don't match preceding patterns *)
  ]
]
```

Note that it is not possible to keep `Function[...]` unevaluated when there is no match.

Comment: Why not replace `0` with `x`? Or `Switch[#, a | b, 1, _, #] &;`

Comment: @Somos There are many possibilities. My point was that one _must_ choose something. It's up to the OP to make the appropriate choice for their application.

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to present some more possibilities.